# Joomla 3 Articles » Category List Very Slow, all other pages fine

Tags: joomla3.0

I use Articles » Category List on a number of pages coming from the menu. I don't know another option for what I am doing. For instance if you go to http://www.historygraphicdesign.com/the-age-of-information and click on The Digital Revolution and Beyond. This one seems to be the slowest which also has the most articles in the list. This leads me to believe it has something to do with searching for articles to list? I've tried extensions to speed up performance but these are always slow.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I looked at this and it seems the apis.google.comA script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script will complete.

Script: https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en.aKKRQLO52_4.O/m=plusone/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=EQ/rs=AItRSTOHUOGH9d8mf_YaeFTDxQ7DaveP4A/cb=gapi.loaded_0:21

Answer (score 0):

Open the console of your browser.

Look at the network and you'll see an error (not from Joomla).

[image]

Comment: I looked at this and it seems the apis.google.com is going crazy at bottom of page loading. I tried to look this up and seems associated with the g+ button or ads. I removed and still slow. I also get the error/warning below when page is loading. This makes me believe this apis.google is a problem but don't know what to do.

Comment: A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script will complete.

Script: https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en.aKKRQLO52_4.O/m=plusone/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=EQ/rs=AItRSTOHUOGH9d8mf_YaeFTDxQ7DaveP4A/cb=gapi.loaded_0:21